# PHP include path different on different servers

Tags: php, include, include-path

In my site, i have a place that says:

```
include('../tpls/header_home.php');
```

and it works. Now i am moving the site to another server, where i get the error:

```
Warning: include(../tpls/header_home.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/usern/public_html/site/tpls/static/home.php on line 4
```

now if I replace the line with this one, it works:

```
include('site/tpls/header_home.php');
```

I could change it, but i don't know how many more places I have of broken paths all around, not only in templates, but files, uploads etc.

I would rather fix the problem generally from a setting or something else I am missing. What do I do?

HINT:

Old working server gives me CWD:
`/home/ortho/public_html/site/lib`

New server that is problematic gives me CWD:
`/home/orthosho/public_html`

why?

STRUCTURE:

`/home/usern/public_html/site/tpls/static/home.php`
`/home/usern/public_html/site/tpls/header_home.php`

PHP old server: 5.2.17

PHP new server: 5.3.8

maybe that is causing problems?

Comment: Could you do an `ls` on both servers, standing in the root of the "webpage"?

Comment: I don't have access to shell. I can CWD from files if you tell me which files?

Comment: If we look at it this way, the first include statement indicates that it's "up one level", then down to `tpls/`. However, the next include statement indicates that you're already "up one level", hence the `../` rendering it way off. Seems to me as if the structure has changed?

Comment: please check the hint and paths, they have different CWD, why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you basically answered your own question.

Create a settings file where you keep all of these specific paths as variables or otherwise, and include that file wherever you need to reference the paths. That's generally how it works.

settings.inc.php:

```
$_CONFIG['BASE_DIR'] = "/var/www/yoursite.com/";
```

some_file.php:

```
require 'settings.inc.php';
include $_CONFIG['BASE_DIR'] . "some_dependency.php";
```

I assume you are trying to fix the issue having already made the entire system, without a common settings file, in which case I don't have an answer. You should really centralise things as soon as you start coding to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: yes, you and shaddy put a similar solution which is great for development, but i don't want to change things all around the site, just fix the setting that breaks my new server that has identical code to old one that works, i added a hint, maybe it can help?

Answer (score 0):

You must have config file, which will have the abosolute path to your site, ofc it will be relative (no need to be hardcoded url) and then use it in all include calls.

Let me explain you, lets say you have a folder in your site called config and in in file called config.php. If you want you could make config class that will hold all your important variables. One of them should be

```
$ROOT_PATH = str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/';
```

That will be root path relative to your project. Then you can simply call this variable elsewhere when you include something:

```
require_once $ROOT_PATH . 'blabla/test.php';
```

Alternative to fix your broken code is to redefine include path with set_include_path()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

But for future, learn to code smart :)

Comment: i understand, and this is great for development, but in this specific case I don't want to redo the entire huge site, just fix the setting that gives me the difference between the two servers that have identical code but one works, and the other doesnt. Can you see the HINT i put also, maybe it will give away a clue

Comment: as I told you you can view the current include path in your old server with get_include_path. You can redefine include path in your new server with set_include_path.

Comment: working server: `include_path .:/usr/lib/php`, non-working server: `include_path .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php` it looks to me that shouldn't be the problem, or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given your new information, the problem is the following:

```
Old server => ~/public_html/site/lib
New server => ~/public_html
```

Why? Well, it's because you've set it that way. How do you access the previous website? `yourdomain.com/site/`, or just `yourdomain.com`? If it's the first one, then it's bound to be that you've got different web roots.

Now, what you're trying to include is this:

```
Old server => ~/public_html/site/tpls/...
New server => ~/tpls/
```

That doesn't quite look right does it?

My guess is that you'd need to [alter the document root in `httpd.conf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) in some way.

Comment: Both sites are accessed the same way, just the domain.com, could it still be document root in this case?

Comment: That's your best bet, yes. The document root isn't visible to the user as far as I know of, it's more like moving the websites root internally.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to use dirname so its really relative to the current file. this is what I use if I make cronjobs, and its more "portable" this way

```
<?php
    include dirname(__FILE__)."/../tpls/header_home.php";
```